# How to center an R plot after removing axis labels

Tags: r, margin

I'm working on visualizing a matrix in R (almost exactly like http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixPlot.html), and I've been using

```
image(<matrix>,axes=FALSE)
```

to draw the picture. However, I noticed that with the y-axis turned off, the plot isn't centered--the space is still there for the axis ticks + label. I can finagle some centering with

```
par(oma=c(0,0,0,2.5))
```

but this seems inefficient and error-prone (if my matrix were to change dimensions/become non-square). Is there a better way to force the graphic to center?
[Reference image http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/9891/metropolis.png](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/9891/metropolis.png)

The right hand margin is significantly smaller than the left.

Comment: I'm stumped too...; ' figured I'd keep you company ;-)   It appears the extra space is a placeholder for the axis' ticks and numeric values (not for the label).  when such axis is shown it does appear centered.  (no help w/ matrices of course, where axes are typically not desired...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does

```
par(mar=c(5,2,4,2)+0.1)
```

help?

Comment: That does it! I see now that the mar default = c(5,4,4,2)+0.1 "lines", do the axis labels typically occupy exactly 2 lines?

Comment: I think one line for the label of the variable and one line for the labeling of the tick marks

Comment: Just a minor comment. There is a typeset and the code should read `par(mar = c(5, 2, 4, 2) + 0.1)`